# how to scale divs content equal to browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm messing around with a special case a customer wants. Back in the days, we all know the advantage of Flash where it's very simple to scale things up and down with just simply give `width`s and `height`s of the file.

Exactly this is what I want to do with a div-wrapper. As seen in this [picture](http://jobs.super-sized.de/test.jpg) 
this is similar to the enter-page. What I would like to archieve is, if the browser-window scales all squares keep the same aspect-ratio and get smaller or bigger.

Assuming I'm using divs with background-images and the markup is something like this:

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="pic1"></div>
  <div id="pic2"></div>
  <!-- and so on -->
 </div>
</body>
```

is there any `css` or `jquery` solution to make this possible?
Any hints are much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't it work if you set `max-width` and `max-height` CSS properties to 100% for the wrapper div?

Comment: Could you add a fiddle? Is there gonna be a background image? Do you want to cover the full size of the window with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by Javascript or CSS. However, for text adjustments I suggest you do it through Javascript, but if you need full browser compatibility and assured effectiveness, you should rely on plugins that give you a good control over what you are doing (building this without them can consume unnecessary time).

**Through CSS** you can attribute the images' `width` and `height` with percentages `relative` to the body's total size.

for example: **[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/ezRZ5/14/)**

```
html, body{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
img{
   position:relative;
   width:50%;
   height:100%;
}
```

**Through Javascript** you can choose from various plugins such as:

- [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/)
- [ResponsiveImg](http://responsiveimg.com/)
- [JQuery Picture](http://jquerypicture.com/)

**For more detailed info check this out:**

- [Which responsive images solution should you use?](http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/)
- [Choosing a responsive image solution](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/)

Comment: could you provide a fiddle with 9 backgrounds, as in my example. Just for understanding!

Comment: @supersize 9 paralel backgrounds? Or grid like?

Comment: grid like, like in my example picture in the OP.

Comment: @supersize Updated the fiddle on the answer, is that it?

Comment: yep, it is! Thanks for the fiddle and the detailed answer! I wish there would be a solution to force the browser to be scaled in a fixed aspect ratio so that they don't deform, but I guess that isn't allowed!

Comment: No, unfortunately for projects like yours browsers weren't meant to do that. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

Give each picture div a class `pic_class` that has fluid % width and height values set. Something in the css file like: `.pic_class{width:33%; height: 33%}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS or with jQuery:

**CSS**

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/ASfUk/
**jQuery**

```
var windowsWidtdh = $(window).width();
var windowsHeight = $(window).height();
$('#wrapper').css('width', windowsWith + 'px');
$('#wrapper').css('height', windowsHeight + 'px');
```

Comment: sorry if I was a little bit unclear, but it's not that I have only one image which should fit the browser window. Each square in my example picture is an own div inside the wrapper with a background-image. But its also okay to use an image-tag!

Comment: @supersize what do you want to happend when the user resizes the window in one section. The height or the with will make the image not to be full screen unless you use `cover`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS at all for this. It's all just CSS

```
#wrapper,.flexbox img {
    width: 100%;    
}
.flexbox {
    width: 33.3%;
    float: left;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/RHK8P/3 for more details.

Edit: Based on your picture, there's 3 images per row, so I updated the flexbox to 33.3%.